# Is it a security risk to require passwords to be unique across all users?

Tags: passwords

More specifically, if Bob Smith uses 123456 as his password, no other user in the system can use 123456. This seems like a security risk to me. Technically, if someone knew something about Bob (he likes UCLA and fishing) and were to change their password using guesses for what Bob might use (Tr0janFi$h) and these passwords met the complexity requirements, but suddenly one was rejected, they'd have a good idea that Tr0janFi$h (or whatever) was Bob's password. This is likely more of a risk in smaller systems where the users are more likely to know each other, but is, technically, a risk in any system. Or so it would seem to me. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure why a strong, unique password would be a security risk. I do not think good passwords unknown by others are a security risk.    ......  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-an-8-character-password-could-be-cracked-in-less-than-an-hour/

Comment: What system rejects a password because another user has already chosen it? Password uniqueness, when implemented, is normally enforced on a per-user-basis to insure they don't reuse their own old passwords.  Do you have a specific example of this that prompted this question?  It seems hard to believe anyone would implement this.

Comment: Yes. It is definitely a security risk. You have described the reasons pretty well yourself, not much to add here

Comment: Also there is no functional justification for such a requirement. Just make sure that the password is "strong", then the chances of duplicates will be nearly zero.

Comment: In addition, a secure system is not supposed to know the passwords and should not be able to "compare" with the existing ones. Even in encrypted form (as each encryption should use some salt/nonce/other user data)

Comment: The password algorithm that is typically used is normally used with a user specific salt, and the number of iterations (thousands) makes it virtually impossible to brute force. Your question doesn’t really have enough information to answer

Comment: What system requires that all passwords ae unique? Being able to ***enforce*** that rule requires a breach in security ... So this seems like a faulty thought experiment or bad design that needs to be fixed regardless of this particular weakness.

Comment: Let's just say that I know of such a system - not written by me - that is being hardened and part of that is that the requirement for a password to be unique across all users is being removed. I've never heard of such a requirement or come across it until this one. The question was mainly to confirm that it is indeed a security risk, which was my feeling when I ran into it. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: John - I'm not sure you understood the question properly.

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is effectively allowing a user to test a password against every account on the system at once, which makes it much easier to for them to guess or obtain a valid password.

---

Imagine that we have a system with 1,000 users, I have a list of 100 common passwords, and 1 user on the system has a password in my list.

In a normal setup, I would have to make a maximum of 100,000 login attempts to compromise a user account (although likely fewer depending on how lucky I am).

With this system I have to make a maximum of 100 attempts to find the password, and then a maximum of 1,000 requests to work out which user it applies to - so up to 1,100 requests in total. And since I'm only ever trying 1 password per account, I probably won't trigger any account lockout either.

So by implementing this functionality, in this instance I you've made it ~90x easier for me to guess another users password and compromise their account.

---

Any minor security benefit you gain from telling a user "don't use this password" is dwarfed by the *signifiant* security issue you cause by telling them "another account on this system is using this exact password".

Comment: Thank you. When I ran into it, I immediately perceived this as a security risk, but I can't say I'm a security expert, so I thought I'd ask if other people viewed it as a risk, also. Of course, these days we all have to be more of security expert or at least work real hard at implementing best practices.